# Airflow - Variables among task

Tags: airflow

How do I create a variable in DAG level and pass on to multiple task?

For example :

```
cluster_name = 'data-' + datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%f")
```

I have to use the above variable cluster_name in all task. but I see value keep changing. I do not want to use xcom. Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This value will change all the time because the DAG definition is being parsed repeatedly by the scheduler/webserver/workers, and `datetime.now()` will return different values every time it is parsed.

I highly recommend against using dynamic task names.

The date is already part of a task in the sense that the execution date is part of what makes each run of the task unique.

Each task instance can be identified by: `dag_id` + `task_id` + `execution_date`

To uniquely identify the tasks, use these things instead of bundling the date inside the name.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in an [Airflow Variable](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#variables) and it should be accessible to all your tasks. Just note that it is a database call each time you look up a Variable.